# Android with date time change, but put on time again, Firebase just return expired token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, kotlin

I was doing some tests on my app, changing the mobile current date to the future. Like 2, 4, 7, 10 days forward. Then I put the mobile on the current date again.

I'm using Firebase to authenticate, but for now on, it's only return expired token. I already tried to reboot the mobile, reinstall the app, and the issue persist.

On others phones works correctly, which I didn't changed the date.

PS: The issue happens on a Sansung S5.

This is how I'm getting the token, and everytime I make a request to my server I'm getting the token again. By the way, I'm using Firebase web custom token.

```
        var mUser: FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser

        mUser?.getToken(true)
        ?.addOnCompleteListener { it ->
            it.result.token

        }
```

Comment: facing the same problem. did you get any solution?

Comment: I'm simply didn't used this phone for a while, than i tried again on this phone, and worked!